# Can't query bigquery correctly - Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have table something like this,

```
+---------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+
|   id    | event_name | event_params.key| event_params.value.int_value|
+---------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+
|    1    |   click    |      stars      |            12               |
+---------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+
|         |            |     level       |             1               |
+---------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+
|    5    |   click    |      stars      |            20               |
+---------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+
|         |            |     level       |             1               |
+---------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+
|    8    |   click    |      stars      |            100              |
+---------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+
|         |            |     level       |             2               |
+---------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+
```

I want average of all average of stars in level, so did some thing like this,

```
SELECT level,
     (SELECT AVG((
        SELECT CAST(d.value.string_value as INT64) 
        FROM UNNEST(event_params)as d 
        WHERE (d.key = "stars"
      ))) as avg_star_at_level 
      FROM `table1`,UNNEST(event_params) as h 
      WHERE event_name = "click" AND (h.key = "level") AND
            h.value.int_value = level)
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,100)) as level
```

But I get something like this "Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported".

So I tried this,

```
SELECT level,avg_token_at_level 
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,100)) as level,
     (SELECT AVG((
        SELECT CAST(d.value.string_value as INT64) 
        FROM UNNEST(event_params)as d 
        WHERE (d.key = "stars"
      ))) as avg_star_at_level 
      FROM `table1`,UNNEST(event_params) as h 
      WHERE event_name = "click" AND (h.key = "level") 
      AND h.value.int_value = level)
```

I got Unrecognized name: level.
How could I query correctly and efficiently?

Result I am trying to produce:

```
+---------+------------+
|  level  |    avg     |
+---------+------------+
|    1    |    16.0    |
+---------+------------+
|    2    |    100.0   |
+---------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AVG(avg_star_at_level) avg_all_star FROM (
  SELECT 
    (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'level') level,
    AVG((SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'stars')) avg_star_at_level
  FROM `project.dataset.table1` 
  GROUP BY level
)
```

with result

```
Row avg_all_star     
1   58.0
```